# How can I show an alert message when a website want to use additional storage on computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I create an alert message when a website want to use additional storage on computer in Internet Explorer.
The message is like:

> do you want to allow this website to use additional storage on your
>   computer?

Comment: `var confirmBool = confirm('Do you want to allow this website to use additional storage on your computer?');`

Comment: Do you mean when your website wants to download a file to the user's computer?

Comment: Sorry, I should be more clear.I am using cache and Index DB in my website.All I want is if someone's browser's cache and database size is set  less than my website's Index DB size in that case I want to show an alert message to user to increase his/her browser's cache and Index DB size.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons MSIE browsers initially allow a maximum of **10Mb** of local storage per website.... Other browsers are yet to mitigate this possible security flaw.

> Tools>Internet Options>General tab, Browsing History section,
>   'Settings' button, Website Databases and caching.

Either increase the allowed storage limit or uncheck the option to allow websites to use local storage.

for more info you can follow https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/419350ab-84d2-4b63-97ee-439b59749b05/do-you-want-to-allow-outlookcom-to-use-additional-storage-on-your-computer?forum=ieitprocurrentver

Comment: Hi Akshay,
Thanks for your reply but can I show end user a message or an alert to notify him for increasing the space in IE.
All I want is can I create an event or something through which I can check browsers cache and database size and give a message to end user accordingly.

Comment: @Adeshkumar see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835209/detecting-if-a-browsers-cache-is-full

Comment: Hi Akshay,Thanks for your help.I have gone though the link you provided.
It is helpful but only in case of cache storage.
That solution I have already implemented in my website.My query is How can I detect setting (Tools>Internet Options>General tab, Browsing History section, 'Settings' button, Website Databases and caching) through java script or j query etc.

Comment: @Adeshkumar sorry,but i'm unable to find it. if you found any please post it here !!

Comment: please go through below mention link-
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/

http://www.noupe.com/development/html5-using-indexeddb-with-webgl-and-babylon-js-79939.html#3-3

Comment: @Adeshkumar thanks, have you succeeded in your attempt to display erorr message ?

Comment: Hi Akshay,Yes.I have followed instruction given in below link-
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/
and I am able to add alert message.